# Filtering a deep json hierarchy with Linq

Tags: linq

Given the json below I want to project into a new type where `WorkflowStepName="Translate"` and `Status="FINISHED"`.

**My Attempt which doesn't work**

```cs
var y = statuses.Where(s => s.Jobs.Any(j => j.Steps.Any(js => js.WorkflowStepName.Equals("Translate") && js.Status.Equals("ACTIVE"))))
        .SelectMany(s => s.Jobs.Select(j => new JJob()
            { ProjectId = s.ProjectId, JobId = j.JobId, Name = j.FileName, TargetLanguage = j.TargetLanguage}));
```

```
[
    {
        "Activity": "ARCHIVED",
        "CompletionStatus": "FINISHED",
        "Jobs": [
            {
                "CompletionStatus": "FINISHED",
                "FileName": "j1.xlf",
                "JobId": 1,
                "Steps": [
                    {
                        "AutoStatus": null,
                        "Status": "FINISHED",
                        "WorkflowStepName": "Review"
                    }
                ],
                "TargetLanguage": "ar_EG"
            }
        ],
        "ProjectId": 11,
        "SourceLanguage": "en_US"
    },
    {
        "Activity": "ACTIVE",
        "CompletionStatus": "FINISHED",
        "Jobs": [
            {
                "CompletionStatus": "FINISHED",
                "FileName": "j2.xlf",
                "JobId": 2,
                "Steps": [
                    {
                        "AutoStatus": null,
                        "Status": "FINISHED",
                        "WorkflowStepName": "Translate"
                    }
                ],
                "TargetLanguage": "zh_TW"
            }
        ],
        "ProjectId": 22,
        "SourceLanguage": "en_US"
    },
    {
        "Activity": "ACTIVE",
        "CompletionStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "Jobs": [
            {
                "CompletionStatus": "FINISHED",
                "FileName": "j3.xlf",
                "JobId": 3,
                "Steps": [
                    {
                        "AutoStatus": null,
                        "Status": "FINISHED",
                        "WorkflowStepName": "Translate"
                    }
                ],
                "TargetLanguage": "de_DE"
            }
        ],
        "ProjectId": 33,
        "SourceLanguage": "en_US"
    }
]
```

I can write a static extension which uses nested `foreach` loops to achieve the correct thing but just seems like there should be a way with Linq. Have also tried various sub-selects but I need the flattened data such as `ProjectId` and `JobId` from the top of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try approach your parent level hierarchy references with this [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__) overload:

```cs
var y = statuses.SelectMany(s => s.Jobs.SelectMany(j => j.Steps, (job, step) => new {Job = job, Step = step}), (project, jobStep) => new {Project = project, JobStep = jobStep})
                .Where(js => js.JobStep.Step.WorkflowStepName.Equals("Translate") && js.JobStep.Step.Status.Equals("FINISHED"))
                .Select(j => new JJob { ProjectId = j.Project.ProjectId, JobId = j.JobStep.Job.JobId, Name = j.JobStep.Job.FileName, TargetLanguage = j.JobStep.Job.TargetLanguage});
```

that basically flattens your hierarchy into a flat list of `Tuple<Project, Tuple<Job, Step>>` (I'm resorting to anonymous objects but idea remains the same), which you then can query and project as you please.